# Using Apache Commons Math to determine confidence intervals

Tags: java, statistics, apache-commons-math

I have a set of benchmark data for which I compute summary statistics using Apache Math Commons. Now I want to use the package to compute confidence intervals for the arithmetic means of e.g. running time measurements.

Is this possible at all? I am convinced that the package supports this, however I am at a loss about where to start.

This is the solution I ended up using with the help of Brent Worden's suggestion:

```
private double getConfidenceIntervalWidth(StatisticalSummary statistics, double significance) {
    TDistribution tDist = new TDistribution(statistics.getN() - 1);
    double a = tDist.inverseCumulativeProbability(1.0 - significance / 2);
    return a * statistics.getStandardDeviation() / Math.sqrt(statistics.getN());
}
```

Comment: you return the margin of error?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Apache Commons Math does not have direct support for constructing confidence intervals.  However, it does have everything needed to compute them.

First, use [SummaryStatistics](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/stat/descriptive/SummaryStatistics.html), or some other [StatisticalSummary](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/stat/descriptive/StatisticalSummary.html) implementation to summarize your data into sample statistics.

Next, use [TDistribution](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/distribution/TDistribution.html) to compute critical values for your desired confidence level.  The degrees of freedom can be inferred from the summary statistics' `n` property.

Last, use the `mean`, `variance`, and `n` property values from the summary statistics and the t critical value from the distribution to compute your lower and upper confidence limits.

Comment: this answer lacks some examples

Answer (score 1):

If you still want to calculate binomial in java by using only standard edition You can use below class like below.

```
calling sample BinomialConfidenceCalc.calcBin(13, 100,95.0D);

public class BinomialConfidenceCalc {

    public static double binP(double N,double p,double x1,double x2){
        double q = p/(1-p);
        double k = 0.0;
        double v = 1.0;
        double s = 0.0;
        double tot = 0.0;

        while(k<=N){                    
            tot += v;
            if(k >= x1 && k <= x2){                
                s += v;
            }    
            if(tot > Math.pow(10,30)){                    
                s = s/Math.pow(10,30);
                tot = tot/Math.pow(10,30);
                v = v/Math.pow(10,30);
            }
            k += 1;
            v = v*q*(N+1-k)/k;

        }
        return s/tot;
    }


    public static double[] calcBin(double vx,double vN,Double vCL){

        double vTU = (100 - vCL)/2;
        double vTL = vTU;
        double dl = 0.0;
        double vP = vx/vN;
        if(vx==0){            
            dl = 0.0;
        }
        else{
            double v = vP/2;
            double  vsL = 0;
            double vsH = vP;
            double p = vTL/100;

            while((vsH-vsL) > Math.pow(10,-5)){
                if(binP(vN, v, vx, vN) > p){
                    vsH = v;
                    v = (vsL+v)/2;
                }else{
                    vsL = v;
                    v = (v+vsH)/2;
                }
            }
            dl = v;                             
        }

        double ul = 0.0;
        if(vx==vN){            
            ul = 1.0;
        }
        else{

            double v = (1+vP)/2;
            double vsL =vP;
            double vsH = 1;
            double p = vTU/100;
            while((vsH-vsL) > Math.pow(10,-5)){
                if(binP(vN, v, 0, vx) < p){
                    vsH = v;
                    v = (vsL+v)/2;
                }
                else{
                    vsL = v;
                    v = (v+vsH)/2;
                }
            }
            ul = v;
        }
        double dlUl[] = new double[]{dl,ul};
        return dlUl;
    }



}
```

Comment: How does the binomial distribution apply to computing confidence intervals for sample means?