# Apache Math: calculate the confidence interval in a t-test, which has two samples

Tags: java, statistics, apache-commons-math

I am using Apache Math3 to do a Student's t test for a website project. Suppose I have two samples:

```
double[] sampleOne = new double[] {134 ,146 ,104 ,119 ,124 ,161 ,107 ,83    ,113 ,129 ,97   ,123};
double[] sampleTwo = new double[] { 70, 118,    101,    85, 107,    132,    94};
```

This data is copied from https://www.statsdirect.com/help/parametric_methods/unpaired_t.htm

I hope to calculate the confidence interval as shown on the above page. For example:

```
Assuming equal variances 
95% confidence interval for difference between means = -2.193679 to 40.193679
```

I found this SO link:

[Using Apache Commons Math to determine confidence intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564621/using-apache-commons-math-to-determine-confidence-intervals), which shows this method:

```
private double getConfidenceIntervalWidth(StatisticalSummary statistics, double significance) {
    TDistribution tDist = new TDistribution(statistics.getN() - 1);
    double a = tDist.inverseCumulativeProbability(1.0 - significance / 2);
    return a * statistics.getStandardDeviation() / Math.sqrt(statistics.getN());
}
```

This seems not working for two samples in t tests. I did quite research, but was not able to find how to do it with Apache Math3.

Answer (score 1):

I am aware that this might be a really late response, but I will try to answer your question. Assuming you have the two unpaired samples `sampleOne` and `sampleTwo` (they are unpaired since they have different sizes), you can use the following method to compute the t-statistic:

```
DescriptiveStatistics one = new DescriptiveStatistics();
for (double d : sampleOne)
    one.addValue(d);
DescriptiveStatistics two = new DescriptiveStatistics();
for (double d : sampleTwo)
    two.addValue(d);
double tStat = TestUtils.t(one, two);
```

Note that instead of `DescriptiveStatistics` you can use `SummaryStatistics` as well. Instead, if you want the p-value, you can do the following:

```
double pVal = TestUtils.tTest(sampleOne, sampleTwo);
```

Finally, if you want to run the full test with a given confidence level (let's call it `double conf = 0.95`), then you execute:

```
TestUtils.tTest(sampleOne, sampleTwo, 1.0 - conf)
```

Turning to getting the lower and upper margins, there is no-direct way that this is supported by Apache Commons Math. It looks like that the formula could work for an unpaired t-Test, but keep in mind that your samples' variances need to be equal (as indicated by the website you provided).

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is correct, but you need to get the right t statistic, the right standard error to multiply `a` by and the right degrees of freedom.  If you are assuming equal variances, use

`double t = tTest.homoscedasticT(sampleOne, sampleTwo);`

to get the t-statistic.  Then you can recover its associated standard error by dividing it into the difference between the means.

```
double meanDiff = StatUtils.mean(sampleOne) - StatUtils.mean(sampleTwo);
double tSigma = meanDiff / t;
```

Then get a T distribution instance with degrees of freedom equal to the sum of the two sample sizes minus two = 17 and do what you were attempting, only multiplying by the standard error to get the interval half-width:

```
TDistribution tDist = new TDistribution(df);
double a = tDist.inverseCumulativeProbability(1.0 - significance / 2);
double halfWidth = a * tSigma;
```

For the unequal variances case, you need to compute the approximate degrees of freedom.  See the protected method `df` in the Commons Math TTest sources for that case.  The code above gives the same results as those in your link for the equal variances case.  For unequal variances, I think the reference has an error, as they appear to use 17 as degrees of freedom in the t-distribution while the statistic itself is computed using pooled variance.